# Python OpenCV Image Transforms or Better

Tags: image, opencv, editing

I have a picture that i'd like to resize to a larger size, the resolution falls behind when I make the image larger. I need a better solution, this is using OpenCV. I wonder if there is a library out there specifically for resizing images and not losing quality? I can't find one myself. So, I turn to stack overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increasing image scale and maximizing resolution using opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174882/increasing-image-scale-and-maximizing-resolution-using-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to resize an image with openCV is to use its `resize` function. Note that you can change the interpolation method (bilinear by default) to a better interpolation method (bicubic gives better results if you want to increase your image's size). Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize).

Answer (score 0):

This problem has drawn attention of many researchers, and hence there are many algorithms with machine learning and deep neural networks [algo1](https://github.com/alexjc/neural-enhance), [algo2](https://github.com/david-gpu/srez) to get your work done, However in the OpenCV library you may use [`superres`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/superres/doc/super_resolution.html) module to get your job done.